# How do I add a widget to my web app in run time permanently?

Tags: flutter, web

I am coding an web app that allows the user to create a type of electronic document using widgets (that I then store in a list view). Is it possible to add this list view to my web app in run time so other users on other devices can access the electronic form?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to use some sort of database to hold the resulting "document". You could use Firebase Firestore, the server's file system, or anything else you can connect to. There is no way to easily modify the underlying code, as it is no longer Dart code; it gets transpiled to JavaScript.

Assuming you go with Firestore, you could have something like this:

```dart
CollectionReference documentRef = Firestore.instance
  .collection('forms')
  .document(formId);

documentRef.snapshots().listen((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  // Do something with `documentSnapshot`.
  // setState(() => _updateForm(documentSnapshot.data.data()));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I will try this and see if it works.